# How to use C file in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

I'm trying to get this https://github.com/TheCacophonyProject/voice_scrubbing working on my ubuntu. I've managed to 'make' the thing using

```
make
```

Go me!

But I don't know how to insert any files into it.
I'm pretty sure the app takes a .wav file and edits that file inplace.
So could I get some help with doing this?

All the best

Edit:

Here's my directory contents. I want to find a way of using that mute_low(.exe) file:

```
notebook@heyfinn:~/Cacophony/voice_scrubbing$ ls
Makefile  mute_low.c  README.md   wavefile.h
mute_low  mute_low.o  wavefile.c  wavefile.o
```

And here's the file contents on Jupyter notebooks to explain why I think there is an .exe file there:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean use the C file? Are you trying to compile it and produce a .exe output file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure with 'make' I've already compiled it? So what I want to do is actually use the .exe file

Comment: So what are you asking for? Are you just not sure where the output file is located?

Comment: @FinnMaunsell there are no `.exe` files on Linux.

Comment: Linux don't have folders (they are just GUI artefacts) but *directories*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux you do not have `.exe` files. But instead files are marked with execute permission.

If you look at your [`Makefile`](https://github.com/TheCacophonyProject/voice_scrubbing/blob/master/Makefile), you can see it defines the `TARGET=mute_low`.

This is your executable.

You can run it as

```
./mute_low # in the same directory where you did make
```

If for some reason it doesn't execute and you get errors like

> ./mute_low - Not an executable

you can make it an executable as

```
chmod +x mute_low
```

Finally it would need the file name of the `.wav` file and you can provide that as

```
./mute_low filename.wav
```

Comment: The `chmod +x` is not needed. The compiler will produce an executable

Comment: If you look at the source, your output would be from `printf("Wrote output as '%s'\n",new_name);` where your modified file would be in `"ml_filename"`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am sure it is not necessary. But there are *some old compilers* which don't and I just didn't want to leave out the possibility.

Comment: I never encountered such compilers (and using C compilers since 1980s on Unix systems). Could you name such a compiler today for Linux? BTW, the linker won't make the file executable when it got some error, and then you don't want to `chmod +x` it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Hmm, I agree. I will update the answer to address your comment.